# How does the tkinter canvas.after() method not cause a recursion error

Tags: python, recursion, tkinter

Using the Tkinter *canvas.after()* method to animate a screen seems to be looked upon  more favorably than using an endless *while True:* loop.  When I first saw the *canvas.after()* method, it looked like it should cause a "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error, but it does not.  Why is that?  Is it because it is not returning a value that needs to be held in memory?

Comment: Why do you think it would?  It just does some magic in the background so that the main loop function will call your function every so often.  Why should it call itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't cause a recursion error because it's not recursion.

Tkinter maintains a queue of events. `mainloop` is responsible for iterating through this queue, handling each event in order. When you call `after`, you aren't recursively calling a function, you are simply adding a new item to the queue.

Imagine if, for example, the tkinter event queue was an exposed list. For example, imagine this queue is named `Tkinter.event_queue`. When you do `canvas.after(1000, my_function)`, it's roughly equivalent to doing `Tkinter.event_queue.append((1000, my_function:)`. And, as you can probably see, appending to a list isn't recursion.

Comment: The functions seem all to be structured like this:                                       
    'def move():
        #... adjust coordinates x, y
        root.after(50,move)'

It looks recursive, at least at first glance.

Comment: @PatrickDennis: it may look it, but `after(...)` is almost literally just `append(...)`.,